# Handling multiply user profiles

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hello I'm creating a site, where users have a login system. Users can registre and upload an image. Right now I'm saving the image in a mySQL DB. And I've seen somewhere on the web, that there's another way to handle this, with making it a file and save the URL in the DB instead(Would like to know how this process is done).

The point of the process is, that when a user logs in, the image should be fetched and displayed on a "profile" page. If other people frequently checks this "profile" which approach would be efficient and cause the smallest amount of delay as loading? Is retrieving the image from a DB each time a user checks the "profile" out a bad idea?

Is it possible for a servlet to automatically create a jsp page for each user?

I guess my overall question is: How would one go about multiply user profiles and make them efficiently accessible for other users?

Answer (score 0):

> Is retrieving the image from a DB each time a user checks the
>   "profile" out a bad idea?

Yup, it will consume some of server resource and time, it is not worth doing same task. Rather use session for the same. Sessions are made available for each user.

> How would one go about multiply user profiles and make them
>   efficiently accessible for other users?

As said above, use session. Instead of actual image, keep the image url into session, once fetched from the db.

*Edited*

> Lets say for example that Brad Pitt has a profile and 3000 users
>   checks him out a minute. So instead of retrieving his profile data
>   3000 times. How will session easen the burden?

Here, you need application scope instead of session. Say you have a `Map<UserName,ProfileUrl>` stored in application. Now there is request for `User1`, if there is no `url` then fetch it from db and put it into map else display the same.

Comment: I'm working some with sessions. But could you give me a concrete example to help me grasp is better? 
Lets say for example that Brad Pitt has a profile and 3000 users checks him out a minute. So instead of retrieving his profile data 3000 times. How will session easen the burden?